# Backbone / Marionette models url chaining

Tags: api, backbone.js, marionette

I have a node.js backend using express-resource to manage my mongoose models.

I have a MarionetteJS Frontend.

My example two objects are organization and project.

My server concats the resource to a uri like `example.com/api/v1/organization/12/project`

The ids are unique as i serve them from a mongodb. it would work if i do only `../project/2`

But to receive the projects within an organization i can only do the first one because of the statelessness.

I now have Backbone models on the client side. I determine a base url like `api/v1/organization` this works fine, but how can i get the projects for an organization? Do i have to create a new model with a base url like `api/v1/organization/:orgId/project` ?

How do i do this?

I hope you can understand what i want to say, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var ProjectModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function(attrs, options) {
       if( options && options.organizationId){
          this.urlRoot = 'example.com/api/v1/organizations/' + options.organizationId + '/projects';
       }
   }
});

var ProjectCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   initialize: function(models, options) {
       this.url = 'example.com/api/v1/organizations/' + options.organizationId + '/projects';
   },
});

// fetch one single project, not in a collection
var model = new ProjectModel({id: 4}, {organizationId: 7});
model.fetch();

// fetch all projects
var collection = new ProjectCollection(null, {organizationId: 7});
collection.fetch();
```

When the model is in a collection, it doesn't need a `urlRoot`, since Backbone will use the model's collection's `url` as the base.

Comment: i guess i can create a collection this way as well, but how do i couple them, because if i have a collection with an associated model this model wont fit or am i wrong?

Comment: would be nice for some views